# React project variable is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

This is my first React project and I have this issue: "./src/pages/EventsPage.jsx   Line 64:  'events' is not defined  no-undef". 
Line 64 is {events}.Variable events is declare in line 33. But why 'events' is not defined I don't understand.

Here is the main react component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Events from "./../components/Events";

export default class EventsPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      eventData: {},
      isLoggedin: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5999/events/" + this.props.match.params.userId, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include"
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data["code"] === 200) {
          console.log("OK");
          this.setState({
            eventData: data.events_data,
            isLoggedin: true
          });

          let events = this.state.eventData.map(event => (
            <Events
              name={event.name}
              image_url={event.image_url}
              start_time={event.start_time}
              end_time={event.end_time}
              price={event.price}
              age_from={event.age_from}
              age_to={event.age_to}
              x_coord={event.x_coord}
              y_coord={event.y_coord}
              status={event.status}
              status_id={event.status_id}
              members_total={event.members_total}
              members_needed={event.members_needed}
              owner_id={event.owner_id}
              address={event.address}
            />
          ));
        } else {
          console.log("NOT OK");
          this.setState({
            eventData: data.events_data,
            isLoggedin: false
          });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return { events };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an `events` variable in the `componentDidMount` method and access it in the `render` method. You could instead create the `events` variable in the render method directly, since it will re-run when you `fetch` request is complete and the state is updated.

Also make sure that you set `eventData` to an empty array in the initial state and not an empty object, or you will get an error trying to use the `map` method on it.

```
export default class EventsPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      eventData: [],
      isLoggedin: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5999/events/" + this.props.match.params.userId, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include"
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data["code"] === 200) {
          console.log("OK");
          this.setState({
            eventData: data.events_data,
            isLoggedin: true
          });
        } else {
          console.log("NOT OK");
          this.setState({
            eventData: data.events_data,
            isLoggedin: false
          });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    let events = this.state.eventData.map(event => (
      <Events
        name={event.name}
        image_url={event.image_url}
        start_time={event.start_time}
        end_time={event.end_time}
        price={event.price}
        age_from={event.age_from}
        age_to={event.age_to}
        x_coord={event.x_coord}
        y_coord={event.y_coord}
        status={event.status}
        status_id={event.status_id}
        members_total={event.members_total}
        members_needed={event.members_needed}
        owner_id={event.owner_id}
        address={event.address}
      />
    ));

    return <>{events}</>;
  }
}
```